# Where is the "take comment-war elsewhere" button?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've noticed that when a comment-war sparks (2 users reply to each others comments on the same Q/A multiple times), the system stops it at some point, and links to a chat room where users can discuss the issue instead of flooding the comment-thread with rage.

Now, I just came across this Q: https://serverfault.com/questions/501546/i-changed-my-password-and-now-i-cant-ssh-in

The sheer nature of the question sparked 11 comments in 20 minutes. Instead of waiting for the system to halt the comment-thread (preventing useful comments) and moving the discussion to chat, why isn't there a "Let's take this elsewhere"-button to begin with? It might be useful

Comment: I was under the impression it's 8 comments between a commentor and the OP that causes the link to appear. If anyone else comments inbetween that time the counter is reset and the 8 comments have to start again.

Comment: I can never remember the link, but there is(was?) a URL you could add to a question and force the room to get created at any point in time.

Comment: @Zoredache that would be almost as helpful. *Someone* please find it

Comment: Wouldn't the comments be helpful for future visitors?  Is there a chat log link that is appended to the original question or comments?  There are times when I see clarification in comments that helps understand why the answer fits or doesn't fit in a certain situation.

Comment: tbh the take it to chat feature is pretty useless.  generally when it is an argument at least one person is still giving info useful to the answer and it is not as if they are going to agree their differences and come back to the question with a summary

Comment: Not false... I'm just really annoyed that the auto-chat function disables new comments on posts altogether

Answer (score 8):

It should be the `Do you want take this outside, sunshine?` button.

On a serious note, in general, I'd like to be able to invite people into Serverfault chat. I believe low rep users can't chat, which is a shame.

Comment: The reputation bar for chat is 20 (anywhere on the network if I recall correctly - the account you associate with chat needs 20 rep to talk). The flip side of this is chat `is *NOT* a place for live support` -- that being said, the comment system automatically offers people the opportunity to move an extended discussion into chat, and there's no reason you can't create a room and drop a link in the comments.

Comment: @voretaq7 Although Chat isn't for live support, it's a great place to discuss grey area topics or chat generally

Comment: True - it's just important to observe that line -- extended Q&A/troubleshooting about a particular question should really go in a dedicated chatroom (and the results of that discussion obviously be edited into the question/answer as appropriate)

Comment: @voretaq7, The chat rule `is *NOT* a place for live support` is a rule in the Comms Room and a few other social channels. **That rule is not network wide.**  Lots of people provide live support in the Programming and other channels.  What is the point of the 'take this to chat' link if not to get support in chat?  **The chat system was put in place as a way to augment the Q&A**, not simply as a social feature.

Comment: @Zoredache `I'd like to be able to invite people into Serverfault chat` <-- to me this means "The site chatroom", A/K/A The Comms Room.. I have no problem with the chat system being used to augment Q&A discussion, as long as it is used appropriately (by **creating a room for the question-specific discussion**, and ultimately **merging the results of that discussion back into the question** as edits or a detailed answer capable of standing on its own without the chat room as context)